# Balefire Suicide?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

So, I am at the end of the last book

> Rand is fighting Moridin. Moridin grabs the true power in Shayol Gol. Rand warns him this could burn him from the pattern. Moridin responds that at least it would be an end.

So, why doesn't he just use balefire on himself? Wouldn't this have the same end result? Is it possible?

Comment: Better question, if you committed suicide using balefire, would that erase everything you had done in the preceding minutes, including committing suicide? what would happen?

Comment: Sorry Sean: I VTCed this as a duplicate even though it was actually earlier than the other one, because I thought my answer there (which I posted before seeing this one) also answered this one adequately. +1 to both though :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Balefire your VTC?

Comment: @Seanoseanohay Well, it was also VTCed by the Community bot, which means the OP, which means you, so... :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Fair to claim you used compulsion then and made me do it? lol

Comment: On a serious note it should be impossible to say something is a dup of a newer post. I see this as bug with stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Balefire burns the last things you did from the pattern, it does not destroy your soul and you can be reborn. The reason why the Dark One is unable to ressurect someone killed by balefire, is that he needs to snatch the soul right after death. Since balefire basically kills you retroactively the Dark One has already missed his opportunity when he realizes that you are gone.

See http://www.steelypips.org/wotfaq/2_nondark/2.3_one-power/2.3.07_balefire.html for details.

Moridin wants to escape the entire cyclic nature of time, e.g. wants to be completely annihilated.